# Xamarin: How to align imageview on bottom of screen?

Tags: android, xamarin, imageview, scrollview

I already looked up some solutions but they all don't seem to work.
The problem is that there is a scrollview?
The imageview with id bottombar needs to be on the bottom.

The frame layout and linear layout on the bottom is one of the solutions for a scrollview I've found here on Stackoverflow but it doesn't work either.

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

        <Button
            android:text="Naar volgende stap"
            android:layout_width="1000px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn_SecondForm"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130px"
            android:layout_marginTop="150px" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="50px" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40px"
                android:id="@+id/bottombar"
                android:src="@drawable/lader" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <RelativeLayout>
     <ScrollView
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_bar">
     <ImageView
        android:id=@+id/bottom_bar
        android:alignParentBottom="true"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: When I do that, my whole screen turns black. Thanks anyway Keshav!

Comment: Please use dp everywhere, remove px.

Comment: Also, height of scrollview should be wrap content